# U.S. banks with their own financial aggregator online tool?

Tags: united-states, banking, online-tools, online-banking

What banks in the U.S. have their own financial aggregator?

I know two banks in Canada have them: [RBC’s myFinanceTracker](http://www.rbcroyalbank.com/myfinancetracker/) and [BMO’s MoneyLogic](http://www.bmo.com/moneylogic/signup.html).

I don't expect a better product than [Mint.com](http://mint.com), but at least something similar were you don't have to give out your bank's credential to third party sites?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Service Credit Union](https://www.servicecu.org/FinanceWorks/home.html) offers FinanceWorks from Intuit.

This (and anything like it) would aggregate your information from that bank, but obviously if you want to pull together all of your accounts from multiple institutions you're going to have to share your info with whomever is running the aggregator.